# routing based on incoming interface

Tags: url-routing, portforwarding, bgp, ospf

need help with the following requirements.
I have 2 routers, lets call A and B. A is the main gateway it has multiple exits to send traffic to the internet. Connected B to A (link 1) with iBGP.  router B push some routes to A. so,A will forward that traffic to B . B will analyze that traffic and if permitted it will put that traffic back to A on link 2.    Now A has to send that traffic to internet exit paths. We tried following but no luck. in B iBGP we added route-map with community-string, so A receives routes with community string from B. and create policy based routing in A in 2nd link(there it receives traffic back from B) mentioning deny community string routes with community-string which came from B, so it has to look for routes without community-sting. but it's not forwarding to A exit links. is there any other option in BGP or in routes to select routes based on incoming interface.

Basically in A if traffic received on 2nd link , it shouldn't put back that traffic to B again. it has to choose other routes apart from routes that came from B.

Any help much appreciated